# Why can't I find kit options on QT Quick application on MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, qt, qml

I can't find kit option on creating qt quick application on MacBook Air. I am new to programming.

[image]

I tried installing Xcode for Mac as suggested by QT team, but my version of Mac doesn't support. Is their any alternative?

Comment: Did you install a Qt version alongside QtCreator? How did you install creator? Via the Maintenance Tool https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/get-and-install-qt.html?